# How can I solve two Chromium browser error messages in intranet environment?

Tags: chromium, intranet

In an intranet environment that I help administer, I'm trying to set up an HTML page to auto-play video whenever we access it. However, I get this from the Chromium browser on load:

error.name = Not Allowed Error
error.message = play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first.

Any suggestions on how I might overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In the end, we employed the following solution to do away with the pesky requirement that a user interact with an HTML page before it can do its thing.

To allow autoplay on pages when you have full control of the client Chromium browser (as our intranet setting permits), create a text file in the Raspbian directory

etc/chromium-browser/policies/managed

and name it

policies.json

Its contents should be the following line:

{"AutoplayAllowed"=true}

If additional policies are set at the same time, just make new .json files in the same directory, in the same format (e.g., a file named "policies2.json").